# Raspberry Pi Zero connected through USB with laptop need to share wi-fi

Tags: usb, ssh, wireless, pi-zero

I am trying to install poison Tap on my raspberry pi as i need it for a project at university. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYDa_VDbjPY&t=95s . I managed to set up an usb connection and SSH to my pi. However one of the steps that I must take is to download the software from github(thus i need git). To install it i need Wi-Fi which I currently don't have.

I tried buying an USB hub with multiple ports but in my setup i need an OTG usb->micro-usb connector and that piece ruins my ability to SSH on the raspberry(don't know why but I can't use this solution).

I was wondering if I can share the wi-fi between the laptop and my Raspberry Pi Zero through the USB connection and still be able to ssh on the Pi with putty?(and how to do that obviously)

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE.  Be sure to take the tour to see how this works and to earn a badge:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a few months old, but I think, people still encounter this issue when trying to configure a Pi Zero over USB.

So:

You can simply make a network bridge from the USB connection to the WiFi. On MacOSX this is done in the system settings via network share:

[image: Share Wifi Network with USB Adapter (Mac)]

In Windows it's in the adapter settings, as shown e.g. here: [Network bridging on Windows](https://www.wikihow.com/Bridge-an-Internet-Connection)

Comment: This is perfectly true. I should have posted the answer. Thank you rgw_ch, that is what I did also :)